# Facebook HackBook example

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I imported the facebook HackBook sample app for android and ran in in my testDevice.

After pressing the login button:

[image: User auth screen 1.]

When the user clicks okay it goes to this page:

[image: User auth screen 2.]

And finally when i expect it to move to app, it takes a crazy turn and give me:

[image]

I am really confused why it doesnt come back to my app after authorization.

Comment: Do you have the Facebook app installed? And if so, what version is it? And in your first screenshot, what is the full url (the one that starts with https://m.facebook.com/d)?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to register your app in facebook developer site and get valid access token and change token id in your code and run it. :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to change the token id?

Comment: @I found the root cause of all this. Its a facebook bug. I will update in detail.